# Cannot get version number string from Android Manifest file

Tags: android

I have an android manifest file with version attributes. But, when I read these attributes from my code, it is return same value even I changed the values in manifest file. The following code is what I am writing and please let me know what was wrong in my code.

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_about, container, false);

        TextView txtVersion = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.about_text);

        FragmentActivity activity = getActivity();
        final PackageManager packageManager = activity.getPackageManager();

        try{
            if(packageManager != null){
                PackageInfo packageInfo = packageManager.getPackageInfo(activity.getPackageName(),0);
                txtVersion.setText(packageInfo.versionName); // get same value even make changes in manifest file.
            }
        }
        catch (NameNotFoundException ex){
            Log.e("tag", ex.getMessage());
        }
        return rootView;
    }
```

Comment: have you tried to clean the project?

Comment: have you tried Build.VERSION.CODENAME variable ?

Comment: I tried to clean the project and rebuild but it's not OK. And I also tried Build.VERSION.CODENAME variable and it shows 'REL' not the version number I set.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you do:

```
txtVersion.setText(packageInfo.versionName); // get same value even make changes in manifest file.
```

and a few lines later:

```
txtVersion.setText("");
```

This will clear the `TextView`, won't it? :)

So, if `packageManager` is not null, you will change the value of the `TextView`, then come out of the `try-catch` and then clear the `TextView`

Comment: Sorry, actually there no such thing in my code. I wrongly added txtVersion.setText(""); when showing my example code. I apologise for my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

this is your try/catch code :

```
try{
        if(packageManager != null){
            PackageInfo packageInfo = packageManager.getPackageInfo(activity.getPackageName(),0);
            txtVersion.setText(packageInfo.versionName); // get same value even make changes in manifest file.
        }
    }
    catch (NameNotFoundException ex){
        Log.e("tag", ex.getMessage());
    }

    txtVersion.setText("");
```

first you are checking `if(packageManager != null)` then `txtVersion.setText(packageInfo.versionName);` ==> txtVersion is set

then catching the exception  `catch (NameNotFoundException ex)`

finaly after all those `txtVersion.setText("");` ==> txtVersion is empty

so just remove  `txtVersion.setText("");` an it will work as you want

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to clean the project, then rebuild
2. Close the application before re-running. If you only change the version in a manifest and do not change the actual application code, it's possible that your application is not recompiled, but just brought to the foreground

Answer (score 0):

Just had this problem and found solution.

If you use Android Studio and Gradle then `versionCode` and `versionName` are overwritten by Gradle.

In order to change this values change it in `build.gradle`